# Perform an action every n Hours, Days, Weeks, Months

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a C# winform. The form has controls that allows a user to pick a date and time and an action will be performed at that date and time only once. I do that like this :

```
private async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // A false trigger means the action has not been performed.
            if (!TimerTrigger &&
                selectedDateTime - DateTime.Now <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
            {
                await SaveFilesAsync();
                // The action was triggered to set to true.
                TimerTrigger = true;
            }
        }
```

And once TimerTrigger is set to true, that means the action was performed and the timer is disabled until there user changes the date or time to the future.

Now that I have that working how I want it to, I have decided to add a new feature. The new feature will allow the user to set the frequency that the action is performed. For example, if the user selects a date and time, the action will be executed at that date and time and then the user can use an up down control and a combobox control to select the frequency. So the user can input 1 in the updown and select weeks in the combobox and the action will be performed every week at the same time based on the input from the date time picker.
I can't figure out the logic on how to do this.

Here is what I was thinking at first:

```
private async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // A false trigger means the action has not been performed.
            if (!TimerTrigger &&
                selectedDateTime - DateTime.Now <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
            {
                await SaveFilesAsync();
                // The action was triggered to set to true.
                TimerTrigger = true;
            }
//SaveFrequencyUnit is either Hours, Days, Weeks, Months and is got from a combobox
          //SaveFrequencyValue is a double that comes from the updown control
           if (SaveFrequencyUnit != null)
            {
                DateTime hoursNewTime = BackupDateTime.AddHours(SaveFrequencyValue);
                if (SaveFrequencyUnit == "Hours")
                {
                    if (hoursNewTime - DateTime.Now <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
                    {
                        hoursNewTime = DateTime.Now;
                        Console.WriteLine(hoursNewTime);
                    }
                }
                else if (SaveFrequencyUnit == "Days")
                {

                }
                else if (SaveFrequencyUnit == "Weeks")
                {

                }
                else if (SaveFrequencyUnit == "Months")
                {

                }
        }
```

I tried to describe it as best I can, let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: Typically this is done with with two separate projects in the solution creating two separate exe files, and then your winforms project will create _scheduled tasks_ in Windows. Winforms is not intended to be left running all the time and won't survive a PC reboot, but the scheduled tasks will.

Comment: I think you almost got it. You just need to have a field that stores the next execution time. The initial value of it is `BackupDateTime.AddHours(SaveFrequencyValue)` (if hours were selected). Lets call that field `nextExecTime`. Then, right after the execution happend, increment that field by the same value again `nextExecTime = nextExec.AddHours(SaveFrequencyValue)`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to explore Quartz.Net?